# Forwarding serial port over network and back to serial char device on remote host (socat?)

Tags: linux, serial, socat

I'm working with a linux application which needs to talk with a remotely-located serial (rs-232) device.  I've worked out how to use socat on the remote end to send the device's serial data over an IP connection, but how do I then convert that IP stream back into a (pseudo) serial device character device (e.g. /dev/fakesocatserial0) on the other side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`PIPE`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/socat.1.html#contenttoc5) address type of `socat` to create a Unix pipe to connect to, for example (assuming that the device with the real serial device creates the network connection):

```
socat PIPE:/dev/fakesocatserial0 TCP-LISTEN:1234
```

Comment: Maybe something like this?  

`socat PTY,link=/dev/fakeserial0,raw,echo=0,wait-slave TCP4:remote-board:1723`

Answer (score 3):

have you tried sshfs? You can simply mount `remote:/dev` into somewhere like `local:/remote/dev` and point to the actual character device

Comment: Well, the remote device is an embedded board with no SSH, so I'm trying to avoid changing its configuration if at all possible.

Comment: ah, then @mgorven 's socat method is the way to go

Comment: This wouldn't have worked anyway -- if you mount the remote /dev locally, it will still be the local kernel that translates the major and minor device numbers of devices into a driver entry point; that is, a /dev/ttyS0 node would still refer to the local serial port, not the remote one, even if the device node happens to be on a remote filesystem.